# There are 10 sticks of length 1,..,10. How many triangles can be formed

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

There are 10 distinct sticks of length 1,..,10. How many triangles can be formed? I do not know whether there are some counting tricks for this one.

Comment: my best guess is at least 6. Any 3 numbers of the form n,n+1,n+2 is good for forming a triangle.

Comment: Are you picking exactly three sticks and asking if they can form a triangle, or do you allow a $4,4,5$ triangle with one of the $4$ sides formed by $1+3$ in a straight line?

Comment: I cannot get more than 4, and for 4 only 9 sticks are enough.

Comment: Can triangles overlap each other? Do the intersections of sticks count as vertices?

Comment: @emanuele I think the triangles are to be formed one at a time. That is, I think the question is how many sets $\{a,b,c\} \subseteq \{1,…,10\}$ satisfy all of $a+b>c$, $b+c>a$, and $c+a>b$.

Answer (score 2):

A first approach is to calculate small values and check OEIS.  Assuming you are asking the number of selections without replacement of three sticks that make a nondegenerate triangle I get $1,3,7,7,13,22\dots$ It is easiest to start from $n=4$, for which there is only one triangle. Then for $n=5$ you just need to count the triangles that include $5$, and so on.  Putting that into OEIS finds [A002623](http://oeis.org/A002623), which the first comment says it is just what you are after.  For $n=10$, there are $50$.  In the formula section we see $a(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}{k+3\choose 3}$ and $a(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n \lfloor(k+2)^2/4\rfloor$

Comment: OEIS is fine, but seems a bit like a cop out.  How do you *compute* an answer for any given $n$?

Answer (score 1):

given the triangle inequality and a hint of euclidean geometry, a triangle(possibly degenerate) can have sides $a,b,c$ with $a\leq b\leq c$ if and only if $c< a+b$

There are $\binom{10}{3}$ ways to select three integers between $1$ and $10$

It should be clear there are $k-1$ ways to write the number $k$ as a sum of two different positive numbers

Lets count how many of these selections leave the larger number bigger than the sum of the other two classifying on the larger number $c$

$c=4: (4-1)=3$

$c=5:4+3$

$c=6:5+4+3$

In general the number of selections of number that cannot form a triangle where $c$ is the larger number is $3+4+\dots+(c-1)$ This sum is  $\frac{(c+2)(c-3)}{2}=\frac{c^2-c-6}{2}$

what we would like is $\sum_{4}^{n}\frac{c^2-c-6}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(\sum_4^nc^2-\sum_n^4c-6(n-3))$

We shall simpify this formula using the formulas for the sum of squares and the gaussian sum to get:

$\frac{1}{2}[(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-14)-(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-6)-6(n-3)]$

This can be further simplified by the reader.

All you have to do is change $n$ for $10$ and you should hopefully get the number of triangles up to congruence that can be created using those sticks (some will be degenerate though).

Comment: I think for c=4 there is only one way to form triangle {1,2,4}. Not 3. Isn't it?

Comment: @YaseenMollik:  that does not form a triangle because $4 \ge 2+1$.  The only triangle with $c=4$ is $\{2,3,4\}$.  You can never use $1$ no matter what $c$ is because the other two sides will differ by at least $1$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry. I intended to write {2,3,4} but mistakenly wrote {1,2,4}. Writer of this answer wrote that if c = 4 there are 3 ways to form a triangle where c is the length of the largest side. But I think only one triangle is possible. That is {2,3,4}

Comment: @YaseenMollik:  He is counting the triplets that fail to make a triangle, so for $c=4$ gets three.  The one that is left is the one you have identified.  For $c=5$ there are $7$ triplets that fail to make a triangle, leaving $3$ that do:  $\{5,4,3\}, \{5,4,2\},\{4,3,2\}$